# jquery/javascript change input for based on value of other input

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm trying to do some math based on what the user enters in an input field. The changes should reflect on another field. The problem is, is that the user can have multiple table rows and the calculations have to be for every row seperate. If I hardcode the row(number) everything is working alright. This is the story:
the user inputs a quantity --> inputs a price --> and the total is calculated instantly.

This is the code that adds another row:

```
    var product_row = <?php echo $product_row; ?>;

function addProducts() {
html  = '<tr id="invoice-product-row' + product_row + '">';

html += '  <td class="text-left" style="width:90px"><input type="text" class="iquantity' + product_row + '" name="invoice_product[' + product_row + '][quantity]" value="" placeholder="<?php echo $entry_quantity; ?>" class="form-control" /></td>';
html += '  <td class="text-left"><input type="text" name="invoice_product[' + product_row + '][product_desc]" value="" placeholder="<?php echo $entry_product_desc; ?>" class="form-control" /></td>';    
html += '  <td class="text-left"><select class="itax' + product_row + '" name="invoice_product[' + product_row + '][tax]" class="form-control">';
<?php foreach ($tax_rates as $tax_rate){ 
$percent_rate = round($tax_rate['tr_rate'],4); ?>
html += '    <option value="<?php echo $tax_rate['tr_rate']; ?>"><?php echo $percent_rate. "%"; ?></option>';
<?php } ?>
html += '  </select></td>';

html += '  <td class="text-left" style="width:140px"><input type="text" class="iprice' + product_row + '" name="invoice_product[' + product_row + '][price]" value="" placeholder="<?php echo $entry_price; ?>" class="form-control" /></td>';
html += '  <td class="text-left" style="width:140px"><input type="text" class="itotal' + product_row + '" name="invoice_product[' + product_row + '][total]" value="" placeholder="<?php echo $entry_total_ex; ?>" class="form-control" /></td>';
html += '  <td></td>';
html += '  <td class="text-left"><button type="button" onclick="$(\'#invoice-product-row' + product_row + '\').remove();" data-toggle="tooltip" title="<?php echo $button_remove; ?>" class="btn btn-danger"><i class="fa fa-minus-circle"></i></button></td>';
html += '  <td class="text-right"></td>';
html += '</tr>';

$('#products tbody').append(html);

$('.iprice2').bind('change keydown keyup',function (){
$('input.itotal2').val((($(this).val()* $('input.iquantity2').val())* 1.21).toFixed(2));
});

product_row++;

}
//--></script>
```

And this part of the code is now hardcoded (and works for only row 2):

```
$('.iprice2').bind('change keydown keyup',function (){
$('input.itotal2').val((($(this).val()* $('input.iquantity2').val())*     1.21).toFixed(2));
});
```

But I want it to be dynamic (for every row). I also tried this but then nothing happens:

```
$('.iprice'' + product_row + ').bind('change keydown keyup',function (){
$('input.itotal'' + product_row + ').val((($(this).val()* $('input.iquantity'' + product_row + ').val())* 1.21).toFixed(2));
});
```

I have a feeling it's syntax related. Could someone please shed a light on this?

Thanks in advance

Comment: you should add ONE class for ALL inputs that You want to handle. For example add class iprice to all ipriceX inputs, and when binding write $('.iprice').bind(...

Comment: Hi, can you explain this a little bit 'cause this confuses me. I give every row a unique number (product_row) so it knows which value to calculate...

Comment: If using jQuery > 1.6, please use `.on()` instead of `.bind()` -- same syntax (.bind is deprecated )

Comment: okay and thanks but using 'on' doesn't make any difference in the output with the same code...

Answer (score 0):

There is syntax error. You need to keep variable name outside string.

Edit: There is also issue of variable scope. product_row is not defined inside event handler. If your product_row variable starts with 1, then you can use index() method to get value of product_row.

JS:

```
$('.iprice' + product_row).bind('change keydown keyup',function (){
    var elemIndex = $("input[class^='iprice']").index($(this))+1;
    $('input.itotal' + elemIndex).val((($(this).val()* $('input.iquantity' + elemIndex).val())* 1.21).toFixed(2));
});
```

Comment: Hi And thanks for posting but that doesn't work unfortunately

Comment: Filling in a value on the quantity input and a value in the price input doesn't do anything on the 'total' input. Which it does when I hardcode the number...

Comment: Try removing keydown event binding and check. At keydown event, the new value entered may not be obtained by val() method.

Comment: unfortunately this also doesn't affect the result in a desired way!

Comment: I tried both, deleting keydown or keyup event with same results.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/87587/discussion-between-chitrang-and-user1264351).

Comment: Hi Chitrang, thank you so much for helping me out with this one and sorry for my late reply on your last post (my wife gave birth today to a great daughter). I had a short moment to test your code but the strange thing is that I have to set the +1 to +2 to make it (seems like to) work. So this:
        $('.iprice' + product_row).bind('change keydown keyup',function (){
    var elemIndex = $("input[class^='iprice']").index($(this))+2;
    $('input.itotal' + elemIndex).val((($(this).val()* $('input.iquantity' +     elemIndex).val())* 1.21).toFixed(2));
});

but I have to investigate more...